# Post to Facebook feed other user not working by java-script sdk

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

The script bellow is working

============ work ==================

```
function postToFeed() {
      FB.login(function(response){    
                 FB.api(                         
                     "/me/feed",
                     "POST",
                     {  
                         "message": "message"
                     },
                     function (response) { });
          } else {              
          }
        }, {scope: 'publish_actions,  user_posts'});
  }
```

============= work =================

The function postToFeed() above works for the Facebook user,
who created the app, but not work for other users.
Then I switch to the new script base on the document of facebook developer: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.5

============= NOT work =================

```
    function postToFeed() {
      FB.login(function(response){      
           check response successful 
           if (response.authResponse) {                  
                 FB.ui({
                     method: "feed",
                     link: "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/",
                     caption: 'An example caption',
                    }, function (response) {}                                       
                 );
          } else {
            console.log("\nlogin error: " + window.authToken);
          }
        }, {scope: 'publish_actions,  user_posts, manage_pages'});
  }
```

============= NOT work =================

```
However it doesn't work, the error occurred, Any help please?
Thanks in advance.
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOIOM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most permissions need to get reviewed by Facebook, else they only work for users with a role in the App. Here´s the documenation about Login Review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Btw, you should never try to use FB.ui in an asynchronous callback function, browsers may block the popup because it does not get opened on user interaction (mouse click).

Comment: Thank luschn for the answer, that I now can solve the issue.